# Spring boot RESTapi

Tags: java

I need to develop a rest api for employee attendance management system. Client is a mobile application developed using angular and ionic framework.

My question is how can I integrate the client mobile application with spring boot rest web services so that the application uses the rest api to login to application and update attendance?

Comment: Please narrow down your question and be more specific, what have you tried and where you stuck?

Comment: @aydinugur I need to develop a rest api to authenticate a mobile app user

Answer (score 0):

create a maven project like below code.

pom file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

 </project>
```

then create Application class :

```
 import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

 import java.util.Arrays;


 @SpringBootApplication
 public class Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }
 }
```

finally you can create RestController, then your application and mobile both can use rest api.

```
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


 @RestController
 public class TestController {

     @RequestMapping("/")
     public String index() {
         return "Hello";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correct, you wish to secure your server side rest api so that you are able to login and only then access it.

1st step (if you do not have at all server side), use code above of hamid or better use spring initilizer (https://start.spring.io/) and select what you need (web and security for sure, jpa could be, rest repositories hmm mayby..).

Then follow the https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication example to secure your web application.

I propose basic authentication and not oauth2!!! I would not propose to start with oauth2 due to it complexity. I simply mention this here so as to ensure you know it exists...

If you wish full flexed user management try to use keycloak with spring boot (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) but this will make things a little more complex for frontend.

Comment: I have developed back end services and mobile application in angular but how I can I integrate both

Comment: Is something like the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rJypX70E4U usefull?

If not tell us what you mean as 'integrate'. Angular have view part and ALSO makes rest requests. Rest has nothing to do with spring boot. Is your question how to make rest requests via angular? How to authenticate in server side using angular frontend? Something else?